# How can i point to a Controller in MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

I have the following route table:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

There are a number of controllers that have been defined. 
I have tried to direct the URL to go to the action of a controller, but that doesn't seem to work.

So if the controller is DetailsController I have set the URL to the following:

`http://localhost:<port number>/Details/Get`

The `Get` in the DetailsController is defined as follows:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
```

It doesn't seem to redirect there, any ideas as to what is wrong?

Comment: you don't need this `[Route("")]` attribute, remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove redundant `[Route("")]` attribute routing here.

Read the link below to have a better understanding

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/